# How to get device set time in swift/ios?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, device

[image]

I want to get time, which user sees in their status bar if they change the time to 24-hour format, or manually select some other timezone with or some other time in Settings, it should be changed in my app as well.

Comment: You would get all of this by default if you are using the proper code to get and display a date. Update your question showing your relevant code and clearly explain what issue you are having.

Comment: If you want to display date/time based on user's setting, do read this documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the time in accordance with the user's settings, use a DateFormatter whose locale is set to the current locale. To be notified when the user changes the locale settings, register for the [locale change notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1418141-currentlocaledidchangenotificati).

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data_formatting